# Question being a mixture of algebraic laws and basic properties of logarithm

Tags: logarithms

****Suppose that x and y are real numbers such that
log<sub>3</sub>(x + y<sup>4</sup>) = log<sub>3</sub>(x − y) + log<sub>3</sub>(x + y),**
and 10 = log<sub>3</sub>(x − 2y) + log<sub>3</sub>(x + 2y).
Find the last two digits of x.**

I got x + y<sup>4</sup>=x<sup>2</sup> - y<sup>2</sup>
and 3<sup>10</sup> = x<sup>2</sup> -4y<sup>4</sup>
using basic properties of logarithm but can't do anything afterwards